# Tub faucet handle will not come off

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

The right tub faucet handle absolutely will not come off and may have become fused. I've tried a variety of ways and angles with maximum personal force (I'm a large guy) and even bought a faucet puller which couldn't make it budge, it's all stuck on there. The left one came off fairly easily. What are my options here? I'm not experienced with plumbing but is there something basic I could do with the faucet pipe pieces? Thanks.

[image: Handle]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Have you tried applying heat?

Answer (score 1):

I will presume you will be rahabbing by replacing valve stems and trim with new. If soaking overnight in penetrating oil, tapping to and fro with a hammer, applying heat, using a puller, etc. has not worked you could always carefully cut it off with a hacksaw.